# Thread-safe map with null-key capability

Tags: java, synchronization, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I need a multi-threaded Map object to use in my web server's caching, and I need to have `null` keys.

`HashMap` allows me to have null keys, but `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't. I tried to create a synchronized version of `HashMap` using `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` but it doesn't accept `null` keys either.

Is there any alternative that I can use, without having to implement some way to wrap the `null` keys?

Comment: HashMap only allows one null key. Are you talking about null values?

Comment: JDK 1.6.0_23, `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` works fine with `null` keys and values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Map` returned by [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) supports all of the features of the `Map` you give it. If you give it a `HashMap`, it supports the `null` key (and also `null` values, you said *"...I need to have "null" key values..."* which can be read either way). What makes you think it doesn't?

This works as expected, for instance:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapTest
{
    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map map;

        try
        {
            map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
            map.put("one", "a");
            System.out.println("Size = " + map.size());
            map.put(null, "b");
            System.out.println("Size = " + map.size());
            System.out.println("map.get(null) = " + map.get(null));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Size = 1
Size = 2
map.get(null) = b
```

Comment: Right, my mistake. I mistakenly used a ConcurrentHashMap for my test, instead of a wrapped HashMap. Thanks.

Comment: @Iravanchi: LOL! Easy to do. Glad that helped,

Comment: This isn't likely a great choice for a server cache.  The cache will need to have very high performance, i.e. negligible locking costs.  ConcurrentHashMap is much better for this.  If you want to allow null values, you can simulate it easily by extending `ConcurrentHashMap` and overriding the `put` method to perform a `remove` when given a null value, after which a `get` for that key will return null, and you still get the much higher concurrency performance.

Comment: Be ware that when using this approach is mandatory to synchronize on the returned map whenever you iterate over the returned collection - see javadoc on `synchronizedMap`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is neither a simple way to make `ConcurrentHashMap` nor an equivalent class supporting `null` keys or values.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is quite different from `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())`.

First of all because a synchronized map will prevent any concurrent accesses to happen simultaneously even if all accesses are read only. `ConcurrentHashMap` won't block concurrent read accesses and, in some cases, may even accept concurrent writes.

But the more important thing is that the `Iterator`s returned by a synchronized map are prone to throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if the underlying map is modified while using the iterator. On the other hand, the `ConcurrentHashMap` iterators' are guaranteed to never throw `ConcurrentModificationException` even if the underlying map is changed while using the iterator.