# How to add null values to ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` which is called from different threads to put values in it. I have to insert null values, but `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't allow `null` values. Is there a way to do that or an alternate option to do this in Java?

Comment: Why do you have to? Give us the use case.

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699794/concurrenthashmap-alternative-with-null-key-capability

Comment: You can use an object which is your "null" instead.

Comment: I have changed the question because there was some confusion in the way I explained it earlier. I don't need a key to be null, but I want values associated to some of my keys to be null

Comment: @gastonmancini they're similar, but the linked question is really asking why `Collections.synchronizedMap()` doesn't allow nulls when backed by a `HashMap` - answer: it does, the poster made a mistake in their test.  I edited the title to be clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using `null`, which has no semantic meaning and is generally considered an [antipattern](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained), represent this "absent" notion as a concrete type that reflects your intent and forces callers to account for it properly.

A common solution is to use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (for pre-Java 8, use Guava's [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)) to represent the absence of a value.

So your map would have a type `ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Optional<Value>>`.

---

Another option is to represent whatever you intend to mean by `null` more directly in the type you're storing in the map, e.g. if `null` is supposed to mean "this used to exist, but no longer" you might create a class structure like so:

```
public abstract class Resource {
  public abstract void doSomething();
  public abstract ClosedResource close();
}

public class ActiveResource extends Resource {
  public void doSomething() { ... }
  public ClosedResource close() { ... }
}

public class ClosedResource extends Resource {
  public void doSomething() { /* nothing to do */ }
  public ClosedResource close() { return this; }
}
```

And then simply have a `ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Resource>`. There are pros and cons to both approaches depending on your exact needs, but both are objectively better than putting `null` values in your map.

---

You might also simply be able to avoid adding `null`s at all - if you can't create a clear semantic meaning for `null` that's different from simply being absent (as suggested above), just use absence in the map to convey what you care about, rather than distinguishing between the absent and present-but-`null` cases.

Comment: Null is not an antipattern, see https://medium.com/@elizarov/null-is-your-friend-not-a-mistake-b63ff1751dd5

Answer (score 3):

One simple answer is "If the value is null, don't try to add it".

Another answer is to take a page from .NET and introduce a Nullable. Your values would be an instance of Nullable.

```
public class Nullable<T> {
    private final T obj;
    public Nullable(T t) {
        obj = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return obj
    }
}
```

You can successfully make instances of Nullable with a null value. You can get the value out with get().

**--- This is the old version of the answer ---**

First, why would you need to put a null key? That would seem like an issue in your design.

That being said, you could use a stand-in object for null. Say your key is KeyLikeThing. Normally a KeyLikeThing has attributes which affect its hash and equals properties. You can have an instance of KeyLikeThing is null in your world. When ever your client wants to put a null, it uses the instance of KeyLikeThing.

```
public class KeyLikeThing {
    public static final KeyLikeThing NULL = new KeyLikeThing();

    // Other KeyLikeThing related stuff.
}

public class Storage<T> {
    private ConcurrentHashMap m = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public T put(KeyLikeThing k, T val) {
        KeyLikeThing kl = k == null ? KeyLikeThing.NULL : k;
        return m.put(kl, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a clearer name than `NULL`, depending on your use case.  For instance you might use `ANONYMOUS` for a `Person` type.

Comment: Your `Nullable` class doesn't implement `.equals()`, meaning operations like `map.containsValue()` will be broken.

Comment: Fair, but it is a demo class.